# Occasional error with div-background-switcher in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a div where I change the background images with a script. I simplified everything here: https://inmeditas.satsang-hamburg.de/test.html
Unfortunately about 10% of the time I get an error in Firefox which looks like this:[image: error in Firefox]
So far everything seems to work fine in Chrome and other browsers. Here is the code as snippet:

```js
/*!
 * jQuery.BgSwitcher
 *
 * @version  0.4.3
 * @author   rewish <rewish.org@gmail.com>
 * @license  MIT License (https://github.com/rewish/jquery-bgswitcher/blob/master/LICENSE.md)
 * @link     https://github.com/rewish/jquery-bgswitcher
 */
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  var loadedImages = {},

      slice = Array.prototype.slice,
      toString = Object.prototype.toString,

      corners = ['Top', 'Right', 'Bottom', 'Left'],
      backgroundProperties = [
        'Attachment', 'Color', 'Image', 'Repeat',
        'Position', 'Size', 'Clip', 'Origin'
      ];

  $.fn.bgswitcher = function() {
    var args = arguments,
        instanceKey = BgSwitcher.keys.instance;

    return this.each(function() {
      var instance = $.data(this, instanceKey);

      if (!instance) {
        instance = new BgSwitcher(this);
        $.data(this, instanceKey, instance);
      }

      instance.dispatch.apply(instance, args);
    });
  };

  // Backward Compatibility
  $.fn.bgSwitcher = $.fn.bgswitcher;

  /**
   * BgSwitcher
   *
   * @param {HTMLElement} el
   * @constructor
   */
  function BgSwitcher(el) {
    this.$el = $(el);
    this.index = 0;
    this.config = $.extend({}, BgSwitcher.defaultConfig);

    this._setupBackgroundElement();
    this._listenToResize();
  }

  $.extend(BgSwitcher.prototype, {
    /**
     * Dispatch
     *
     * @param {string|Array} one
     */
    dispatch: function(one) {
      switch (toString.call(one)) {
        case '[object Object]':
          this.setConfig(one);
          break;
        case '[object String]':
          this[one].apply(this, slice.call(arguments, 1));
          break;
        default:
          throw new Error('Please specify a Object or String');
      }
    },

    /**
     * Set config
     *
     * @param {Object} config
     */
    setConfig: function(config) {
      this.config = $.extend(this.config, config);

      if (typeof this.config.random !== 'undefined') {
        this.config.shuffle = this.config.random;
      }

      this.refresh();
    },

    /**
     * Set images
     *
     * @param {Array} images
     */
    setImages: function(images) {
      this.imageList = new this.constructor.ImageList(images);

      if (this.config.shuffle) {
        this.imageList.shuffle();
      }
    },

    /**
     * Set switch handler
     *
     * @param {Function} fn
     */
    setSwitchHandler: function(fn) {
      this.switchHandler = $.proxy(fn, this);
    },

    /**
     * Default switch handler
     *
     * @param {string} type
     * @returns {Function}
     */
    getBuiltInSwitchHandler: function(type) {
      return this.constructor.switchHandlers[type || this.config.effect];
    },

    /**
     * Refresh
     */
    refresh: function() {
      this.setImages(this.config.images);
      this.setSwitchHandler(this.getBuiltInSwitchHandler());
      this._prepareSwitching();

      if (this.config.start) {
        this.start();
      }
    },

    /**
     * Start switching
     */
    start: function() {
      if (!this._timerID) {
        this._timerID = setTimeout($.proxy(this, 'next'), this.config.interval);
      }
    },

    /**
     * Stop switching
     */
    stop: function() {
      if (this._timerID) {
        clearTimeout(this._timerID);
        this._timerID = null;
      }
    },

    /**
     * Toggle between start/stop
     */
    toggle: function() {
      if (this._timerID) {
        this.stop();
      } else {
        this.start();
      }
    },

    /**
     * Reset switching
     */
    reset: function() {
      this.index = 0;
      this._prepareSwitching();
    },

    /**
     * Go to next switching
     */
    next: function() {
      var max = this.imageList.count();

      if (!this.config.loop && this.index + 1 === max) {
        return;
      }

      if (++this.index === max) {
        this.index = 0;
      }

      this.switching();
    },

    /**
     * Go to previous switching
     */
    prev: function() {
      if (!this.config.loop && this.index === 0) {
        return;
      }

      if (--this.index === -1) {
        this.index = this.imageList.count() - 1;
      }

      this.switching();
    },

    /**
     * Select the switching at index
     *
     * @param {number} index
     */
    select: function(index) {
      if (index === -1) {
        index = this.imageList.count() - 1;
      }

      this.index = index;
      this.switching();
    },

    /**
     * Switching the background image
     */
    switching: function() {
      var started = !!this._timerID;

      if (started) {
        this.stop();
      }

      this._createSwitchableElement();
      this._prepareSwitching();
      this.switchHandler(this.$switchable);

      if (started) {
        this.start();
      }
    },

    /**
     * Destroy...
     */
    destroy: function() {
      this.stop();
      this._stopListeningToResize();

      if (this.$switchable) {
        this.$switchable.stop();
        this.$switchable.remove();
        this.$switchable = null;
      }

      if (this.$bg) {
        this.$bg.remove();
        this.$bg = null;
      }

      this.$el.removeAttr('style');
      this.$el.removeData(this.constructor.keys.instance);
      this.$el = null;
    },

    /**
     * Adjust rectangle
     */
    _adjustRectangle: function() {
      var corner,
          i = 0,
          length = corners.length,
          offset = this.$el.position(),
          copiedStyles = {
            top: offset.top,
            left: offset.left,
            width: this.$el.innerWidth(),
            height: this.$el.innerHeight()
          };

      for (; i < length; i++) {
        corner = corners[i];
        copiedStyles['margin' + corner] = this.$el.css('margin' + corner);
        copiedStyles['border' + corner] = this.$el.css('border' + corner);
      }

      this.$bg.css(copiedStyles);
    },

    /**
     * Setup background element
     */
    _setupBackgroundElement: function() {
      this.$bg = $(document.createElement('div'));
      this.$bg.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: (parseInt(this.$el.css('zIndex'), 10) || 0) - 1,
        overflow: 'hidden'
      });

      this._copyBackgroundStyles();
      this._adjustRectangle();

      if (this.$el[0].tagName === 'BODY') {
        this.$el.prepend(this.$bg);
      } else {
        this.$el.before(this.$bg);
        this.$el.css('background', 'none');
      }
    },

    /**
     * Create switchable element
     */
    _createSwitchableElement: function() {
      if (this.$switchable) {
        this.$switchable.remove();
      }

      this.$switchable = this.$bg.clone();
      this.$switchable.css({top: 0, left: 0, margin: 0, border: 'none'});
      this.$switchable.appendTo(this.$bg);
    },

    /**
     * Copy background styles
     */
    _copyBackgroundStyles: function () {
      var prop,
          copiedStyle = {},
          i = 0,
          length = backgroundProperties.length,
          backgroundPosition = 'backgroundPosition';

      for (; i < length; i++) {
        prop = 'background' + backgroundProperties[i];
        copiedStyle[prop] = this.$el.css(prop);
      }

      // For IE<=9
      if (copiedStyle[backgroundPosition] === undefined) {
        copiedStyle[backgroundPosition] = [
          this.$el.css(backgroundPosition + 'X'),
          this.$el.css(backgroundPosition + 'Y')
        ].join(' ');
      }

      this.$bg.css(copiedStyle);
    },

    /**
     * Listen to the resize event
     */
    _listenToResize: function() {
      var that = this;
      this._resizeHandler = function() {
        that._adjustRectangle();
      };
      $(window).on('resize', this._resizeHandler);
    },

    /**
     * Stop listening to the resize event
     */
    _stopListeningToResize: function() {
      $(window).off('resize', this._resizeHandler);
      this._resizeHandler = null;
    },

    /**
     * Prepare the Switching
     */
    _prepareSwitching: function() {
      this.$bg.css('backgroundImage', this.imageList.url(this.index));
    }
  });

  /**
   * Data Keys
   * @type {Object}
   */
  BgSwitcher.keys = {
    instance: 'bgSwitcher'
  };

  /**
   * Default Config
   * @type {Object}
   */
  BgSwitcher.defaultConfig = {
    images: [],
    interval: 5000,
    start: true,
    loop: true,
    shuffle: false,
    effect: 'fade',
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'swing'
  };

  /**
   * Built-In switch handlers (effects)
   * @type {Object}
   */
  BgSwitcher.switchHandlers = {
    fade: function($el) {
      $el.animate({opacity: 0}, this.config.duration, this.config.easing);
    },

    blind: function($el) {
      $el.animate({height: 0}, this.config.duration, this.config.easing);
    },

    clip: function($el) {
      $el.animate({
        top: parseInt($el.css('top'), 10) + $el.height() / 2,
        height: 0
      }, this.config.duration, this.config.easing);
    },

    slide: function($el) {
      $el.animate({top: -$el.height()}, this.config.duration, this.config.easing);
    },

    drop: function($el) {
      $el.animate({
        left: -$el.width(),
        opacity: 0
      }, this.config.duration, this.config.easing);
    },

    hide: function($el) {
      $el.hide();
    }
  };

  /**
   * Define effect
   *
   * @param {String} name
   * @param {Function} fn
   */
  BgSwitcher.defineEffect = function(name, fn) {
    this.switchHandlers[name] = fn;
  };

  /**
   * BgSwitcher.ImageList
   *
   * @param {Array} images
   * @constructor
   */
  BgSwitcher.ImageList = function(images) {
    this.images = images;
    this.createImagesBySequence();
    this.preload();
  };

  $.extend(BgSwitcher.ImageList.prototype, {
    /**
     * Images is sequenceable
     *
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    isSequenceable: function() {
      return typeof this.images[0] === 'string' &&
          typeof this.images[1] === 'number' &&
          typeof this.images[2] === 'number';
    },

    /**
     * Create an images by sequence
     */
    createImagesBySequence: function() {
      if (!this.isSequenceable()) {
        return;
      }

      var images = [],
          base = this.images[0],
          min = this.images[1],
          max = this.images[2];

      do {
        images.push(base.replace(/\.\w+$/, min + '$&'));
      } while (++min <= max);

      this.images = images;
    },

    /**
     * Preload an images
     */
    preload: function() {
      var path,
          length = this.images.length,
          i = 0;

      for (; i < length; i++) {
        path = this.images[i];
        if (!loadedImages[path]) {
          loadedImages[path] = new Image();
          loadedImages[path].src = path;
        }
      }
    },

    /**
     * Shuffle an images
     */
    shuffle: function() {
      var j, t,
          i = this.images.length,
          original = this.images.join();

      if (!i) {
        return;
      }

      while (i) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        t = this.images[--i];
        this.images[i] = this.images[j];
        this.images[j] = t;
      }

      if (this.images.join() === original) {
        this.shuffle();
      }
    },

    /**
     * Get the image from index
     *
     * @param {number} index
     * @returns {string}
     */
    get: function(index) {
      return this.images[index];
    },

    /**
     * Get the URL with function of CSS
     *
     * @param {number} index
     * @returns {string}
     */
    url: function(index) {
      return 'url(' + this.get(index) + ')';
    },

    /**
     * Count of images
     *
     * @returns {number}
     */
    count: function() {
      return this.images.length;
    }
  });

  $.BgSwitcher = BgSwitcher;
}(jQuery));


$(".amrum").bgswitcher({
  images: ["https://inmeditas.satsang-hamburg.de/headerAmrum1.jpg", "https://inmeditas.satsang-hamburg.de/headerAmrum2.jpg", "https://inmeditas.satsang-hamburg.de/headerAmrum3.jpg", "https://inmeditas.satsang-hamburg.de/headerAmrum4.jpg"],
  interval: 5000,
  duration: 1000
});
```

```css
.amrum {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.unterseite {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="amrum"><img class="unterseite" src="https://inmeditas.satsang-hamburg.de/headerAmrum-hilf.png" /></div>
```

I would love a solution without that mistake and without problems with the Bootstrap 4 Navbar (which some other scripts unfortunately have that I tried).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you know when this error happen ? Is it when you reload the page, or after the background changed ?

Comment: When I reload the page. As I said, it happens only once in a while that error (in my Firefox).

Comment: Ah yes I saw it. It is strange, when I wanted to "examine element" with Firefox dev tools, The image was then well displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now used http://responsiveslides.com/ and so far it works with Bootstrap 4 and I didn't get an error.

```js
/*! ResponsiveSlides.js v1.55
 * http://responsiveslides.com
 * http://viljamis.com
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2011-2012 @viljamis
 * Available under the MIT license
 */

/*jslint browser: true, sloppy: true, vars: true, plusplus: true, indent: 2 */

(function ($, window, i) {
  $.fn.responsiveSlides = function (options) {

    // Default settings
    var settings = $.extend({
      "auto": true,             // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
      "speed": 1000,             // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
      "timeout": 5000,          // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
      "pager": false,           // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
      "nav": false,             // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
      "random": false,          // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
      "pause": false,           // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
      "pauseControls": true,    // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
      "prevText": "Previous",   // String: Text for the "previous" button
      "nextText": "Next",       // String: Text for the "next" button
      "maxwidth": "",           // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
      "navContainer": "",       // Selector: Where auto generated controls should be appended to, default is after the <ul>
      "manualControls": "",     // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
      "namespace": "rslides",   // String: change the default namespace used
      "before": $.noop,         // Function: Before callback
      "after": $.noop           // Function: After callback
    }, options);

    return this.each(function () {

      // Index for namespacing
      i++;

      var $this = $(this),

        // Local variables
        vendor,
        selectTab,
        startCycle,
        restartCycle,
        rotate,
        $tabs,

        // Helpers
        index = 0,
        $slide = $this.children(),
        length = $slide.length,
        fadeTime = parseFloat(settings.speed),
        waitTime = parseFloat(settings.timeout),
        maxw = parseFloat(settings.maxwidth),

        // Namespacing
        namespace = settings.namespace,
        namespaceIdx = namespace + i,

        // Classes
        navClass = namespace + "_nav " + namespaceIdx + "_nav",
        activeClass = namespace + "_here",
        visibleClass = namespaceIdx + "_on",
        slideClassPrefix = namespaceIdx + "_s",

        // Pager
        $pager = $("<ul class='" + namespace + "_tabs " + namespaceIdx + "_tabs' />"),

        // Styles for visible and hidden slides
        visible = {"float": "left", "position": "relative", "opacity": 1, "zIndex": 2},
        hidden = {"float": "none", "position": "absolute", "opacity": 0, "zIndex": 1},

        // Detect transition support
        supportsTransitions = (function () {
          var docBody = document.body || document.documentElement;
          var styles = docBody.style;
          var prop = "transition";
          if (typeof styles[prop] === "string") {
            return true;
          }
          // Tests for vendor specific prop
          vendor = ["Moz", "Webkit", "Khtml", "O", "ms"];
          prop = prop.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + prop.substr(1);
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < vendor.length; i++) {
            if (typeof styles[vendor[i] + prop] === "string") {
              return true;
            }
          }
          return false;
        })(),

        // Fading animation
        slideTo = function (idx) {
          settings.before(idx);
          // If CSS3 transitions are supported
          if (supportsTransitions) {
            $slide
              .removeClass(visibleClass)
              .css(hidden)
              .eq(idx)
              .addClass(visibleClass)
              .css(visible);
            index = idx;
            setTimeout(function () {
              settings.after(idx);
            }, fadeTime);
          // If not, use jQuery fallback
          } else {
            $slide
              .stop()
              .fadeOut(fadeTime, function () {
                $(this)
                  .removeClass(visibleClass)
                  .css(hidden)
                  .css("opacity", 1);
              })
              .eq(idx)
              .fadeIn(fadeTime, function () {
                $(this)
                  .addClass(visibleClass)
                  .css(visible);
                settings.after(idx);
                index = idx;
              });
          }
        };

      // Random order
      if (settings.random) {
        $slide.sort(function () {
          return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);
        });
        $this
          .empty()
          .append($slide);
      }

      // Add ID's to each slide
      $slide.each(function (i) {
        this.id = slideClassPrefix + i;
      });

      // Add max-width and classes
      $this.addClass(namespace + " " + namespaceIdx);
      if (options && options.maxwidth) {
        $this.css("max-width", maxw);
      }

      // Hide all slides, then show first one
      $slide
        .hide()
        .css(hidden)
        .eq(0)
        .addClass(visibleClass)
        .css(visible)
        .show();

      // CSS transitions
      if (supportsTransitions) {
        $slide
          .show()
          .css({
            // -ms prefix isn't needed as IE10 uses prefix free version
            "-webkit-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out",
            "-moz-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out",
            "-o-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out",
            "transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out"
          });
      }

      // Only run if there's more than one slide
      if ($slide.length > 1) {

        // Make sure the timeout is at least 100ms longer than the fade
        if (waitTime < fadeTime + 100) {
          return;
        }

        // Pager
        if (settings.pager && !settings.manualControls) {
          var tabMarkup = [];
          $slide.each(function (i) {
            var n = i + 1;
            tabMarkup +=
              "<li>" +
              "<a href='#' class='" + slideClassPrefix + n + "'>" + n + "</a>" +
              "</li>";
          });
          $pager.append(tabMarkup);

          // Inject pager
          if (options.navContainer) {
            $(settings.navContainer).append($pager);
          } else {
            $this.after($pager);
          }
        }

        // Manual pager controls
        if (settings.manualControls) {
          $pager = $(settings.manualControls);
          $pager.addClass(namespace + "_tabs " + namespaceIdx + "_tabs");
        }

        // Add pager slide class prefixes
        if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
          $pager.find('li').each(function (i) {
            $(this).addClass(slideClassPrefix + (i + 1));
          });
        }

        // If we have a pager, we need to set up the selectTab function
        if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
          $tabs = $pager.find('a');

          // Select pager item
          selectTab = function (idx) {
            $tabs
              .closest("li")
              .removeClass(activeClass)
              .eq(idx)
              .addClass(activeClass);
          };
        }

        // Auto cycle
        if (settings.auto) {

          startCycle = function () {
            rotate = setInterval(function () {

              // Clear the event queue
              $slide.stop(true, true);

              var idx = index + 1 < length ? index + 1 : 0;

              // Remove active state and set new if pager is set
              if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
                selectTab(idx);
              }

              slideTo(idx);
            }, waitTime);
          };

          // Init cycle
          startCycle();
        }

        // Restarting cycle
        restartCycle = function () {
          if (settings.auto) {
            // Stop
            clearInterval(rotate);
            // Restart
            startCycle();
          }
        };

        // Pause on hover
        if (settings.pause) {
          $this.hover(function () {
            clearInterval(rotate);
          }, function () {
            restartCycle();
          });
        }

        // Pager click event handler
        if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
          $tabs.bind("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (!settings.pauseControls) {
              restartCycle();
            }

            // Get index of clicked tab
            var idx = $tabs.index(this);

            // Break if element is already active or currently animated
            if (index === idx || $("." + visibleClass).queue('fx').length) {
              return;
            }

            // Remove active state from old tab and set new one
            selectTab(idx);

            // Do the animation
            slideTo(idx);
          })
            .eq(0)
            .closest("li")
            .addClass(activeClass);

          // Pause when hovering pager
          if (settings.pauseControls) {
            $tabs.hover(function () {
              clearInterval(rotate);
            }, function () {
              restartCycle();
            });
          }
        }

        // Navigation
        if (settings.nav) {
          var navMarkup =
            "<a href='#' class='" + navClass + " prev'>" + settings.prevText + "</a>" +
            "<a href='#' class='" + navClass + " next'>" + settings.nextText + "</a>";

          // Inject navigation
          if (options.navContainer) {
            $(settings.navContainer).append(navMarkup);
          } else {
            $this.after(navMarkup);
          }

          var $trigger = $("." + namespaceIdx + "_nav"),
            $prev = $trigger.filter(".prev");

          // Click event handler
          $trigger.bind("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var $visibleClass = $("." + visibleClass);

            // Prevent clicking if currently animated
            if ($visibleClass.queue('fx').length) {
              return;
            }

            //  Adds active class during slide animation
            //  $(this)
            //    .addClass(namespace + "_active")
            //    .delay(fadeTime)
            //    .queue(function (next) {
            //      $(this).removeClass(namespace + "_active");
            //      next();
            //  });

            // Determine where to slide
            var idx = $slide.index($visibleClass),
              prevIdx = idx - 1,
              nextIdx = idx + 1 < length ? index + 1 : 0;

            // Go to slide
            slideTo($(this)[0] === $prev[0] ? prevIdx : nextIdx);
            if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
              selectTab($(this)[0] === $prev[0] ? prevIdx : nextIdx);
            }

            if (!settings.pauseControls) {
              restartCycle();
            }
          });

          // Pause when hovering navigation
          if (settings.pauseControls) {
            $trigger.hover(function () {
              clearInterval(rotate);
            }, function () {
              restartCycle();
            });
          }
        }

      }

      // Max-width fallback
      if (typeof document.body.style.maxWidth === "undefined" && options.maxwidth) {
        var widthSupport = function () {
          $this.css("width", "100%");
          if ($this.width() > maxw) {
            $this.css("width", maxw);
          }
        };

        // Init fallback
        widthSupport();
        $(window).bind("resize", function () {
          widthSupport();
        });
      }

    });

  };
})(jQuery, this, 0);

  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
  });
```

```css
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="rslides">
  <li><img src="https://inmeditas.satsang-hamburg.de/headerAmrum1.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://inmeditas.satsang-hamburg.de/headerAmrum2.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://inmeditas.satsang-hamburg.de/headerAmrum3.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://inmeditas.satsang-hamburg.de/headerAmrum4.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No. My guess is, it probably has something to do with the transparent image which stretches the div (in the first version).